# Mootools breaks Google maps streetview - black screen

Tags: google-maps-api-3, mootools, google-street-view

Including the mootools.min.js in the Maps JavaScript API Hello World example causes the street view feature to fail rendering street images.   I'm working with Joomla and mootools gets loaded prior to my code getting inserted.

I reduced the problem until I was working with the HelloWorld example provided in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).  My local version of mootools is 1.4.5.   I've tested it with the hosted 1.45 as well as the latest version 1.6.0.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After dropping the street view man onto the street network I see two console errors:

GET about:invalid net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

GET https://example.com/%5Bobject%20Array%20Iterator%5D?panoid=hDKgn2F54H80bzAQMu1LoQ&output=tile&x=0&y=0&zoom=0&nbt&fover=2 404 (Not Found)

The street view interface seems to be working - the nav arrows are displayed and clickable, just no images.

Comment: https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2803

Comment: https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2661

Comment: Seems to be a "known" issue that they didn't fix until now... I would open a new issue on their repository, providing a complete snippet ([this one](https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/bsp7gav8/) should be fine) and referencing this question as well.

Comment: Thanks MrUpsidown, I should have thought to look for a bug report on Mootools.   I updated report 2803 since it's still open.   Your jsFiddle was much clearer than was listed w/2803.