# Streetview Gives blackbox with Navbuttons, no street image, when loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, coffeescript

I'm using react to load streetview into a component I get this :

[image]

As we can see - the map component loads fine, and the streetview component seems to load fine, except that the image behind it (the actual street view) isn't loaded.

The error reported is :

**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined in
>   maps.googleapis.com/imagery_viewer.js:299

**

When I run similar code in straight-up HTML, this works ... sometimes ... often I get no returned image

I've isolated the code into a special function triggered with a large setTimeout() call so that the document load time is not to blame. Indeed, using watches and breakbpoints, we can see that the DIVs are loaded and accessible at run time.

```
 handleLoad: -> 
    options = {
      addressControl: true
      fullscreenControl: true
      panControl: true  
      pov: this.props.image.pov  
      visible: true  
      zoomControl: true
    }
    if this.props.image.pano  
      options.pano = this.props.image.pano  
    else if this.props.image.position
      options.position = new google.maps.LatLng this.props.image.position[0], this.props.image.position[1]

    if this.props.image.position
      pos = new google.maps.LatLng this.props.image.position[0], this.props.image.position[1]  
    else   
      pos = {lat: this.props.entryLatitude, lng: this.props.entryLongitude};

    options.key   ='XXXX - GOOGLE MAP API KEY GOES HERE - XXXX';
    this.map      = new google.maps.Map(this.mapDiv, {  center: pos,  zoom: 14, visible:true } , streetViewControl: false);
    this.panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama this.panoramaDiv, options;
    this.map.setStreetView(this.panorama);
```

Any suggestions what could be causing this problem ?

Comment: It should be mentioned that the controls in the streetview box below all WORK and in fact, navigation performed can be read out easily.

Answer (score 1):

This known black street view panorama issue can be cache or cors related. I suggest you first try ruling both of them out. E.g. see https://support.google.com/maps/thread/6166296?msgid=8836199

It may also be due to a third-party library bug or conflict. E.g. if you're using mootools or prototype.js check out these threads:
[Mootools breaks Google maps streetview - black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57084724/mootools-breaks-google-maps-streetview-black-screen)
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139252493

Another potential reason could be that your lat/lngs are far away from the roads where the street view imagery is available. Have a look at this great answer to related question [Google map JS API "StreetViewPanorama" display black screen for some address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207320/google-map-js-api-streetviewpanorama-display-black-screen-for-some-address)

Let us know if any of the linked solutions work for you; otherwise please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz that reproduces the issue and I'll be happy to investigate further.

Comment: This happens only when in a react component. The same code in "straight" HTML works just fine. 

The location is tested and known to be good. In fact, using the controls on the streetview will return appropriately moved location images (but will not draw them into the control)

Comment: I see, could you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz in that case? Thx